# In Vue can you call the created() function from a method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-framework

So I'm making an app in vue, on page load it takes a cookie with the user's zip and performs a search using that zip, but the user is also allowed to change that zip if its wrong so I want to be able to call the created method from inside a regular method that will run when they change the zip, is that possible in Vue?

Comment: `created` is a life cycle hook could not be invoked in that manner

Comment: So is there a better way to do this without duplicating the function in my methods section?

Comment: create a method call it inside created hook and call it again in your new method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Edited: I thought it's not possible but as @RoyJ pointed, apparently, you can but below is the
>   alternative solution instead of invoking the `created()` hook.

What you can do instead is define another function under your `methods` property which you can call during the `created` hook and when there's a change to `zip` then you can call the same function.

In this way, you define the logic only in one place and just reuse it when you need it.

```
methods: {
  zipCodeRelatedRequest() {
    // core logic here
  },
  handleZipChange() {
    this.zipCodeRelatedRequest()
  }
},
created() {
  this.zipCodeRelatedRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is *possible* using [`$options`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options). But as Ana pointed out, you *should* be defining a method that `created` calls. Calling `created` confuses its purpose. The other method should be named in a way that makes its purpose clear.

Example using `$options`, just to demonstrate possibility:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created() {
    console.log("Created");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="$options.created">Run</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm just curious, how would you invoke it from one of your methods though. It works if you attach it as the event handler but when I tried calling it from my function using `this.$options.created()`, it results to an error stating that `created` is not a function.

Comment: For some reason `this.$options.created` seems to be an array with the function inside it, you can invoke it using `this.$options.created[0]()`

Comment: That's interesting. I assumed that it would be a type of function since it's declared that way, never thought it's like that. Thanks.